# Catch MySQL errors while creating file download in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a 'Download information' button in my web application such that when a user enters 'user_id' and clicks on that button his/her personal information will be downloaded in 'user.txt' file.

I am using PHP as my primary language and MySQL at back-end.

So when user clicks on the button I change the header using:

```
$filename = 'user.txt';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

The data to be exported into the file is being fetched from many tables and is of huge size. And constraint is that I can't hold that much of data on the server. So I have to flush it to file as soon as it is retrieved from database.

But here problem is that I want catch errors at MySQL level. For instance, if there was some problem in executing the query or the table `user_details` does not exists then I want to display a corresponding error from MySQL in user's web browser.
But here in this case, the error gets printed in the file itself.

Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You can check result of query and show error detail by using [mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Do not use mysq_* functions they are deprecated. Use mysqli_* instead. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549439/catch-mysql-errors-while-creating-file-download-in-php/24549520#24549508)

Answer (score 0):

First write query and and you have to check If user found then code for download other wise display error message.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `user_details` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id LIMIT 1");

if(isset( $result['user_id']) && $result['user_id']!="")
{
  $filename = 'user.txt';
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  echo 'Username:' . $result['user_id'] . "\n";
}
else
{
  echo "Error Message";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check query result before downloading file like;

```
$link = some db connections
$result = mysqli_query('your_query');
if (!$result) {
    die('Technical error occured: ' . mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    $filename = 'user.txt';
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    ......
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i removed my comment ^^ (will remove this comment in a few minutes)

Comment: @ashutosh so, what do you want actually? Since, updated text is different from your question

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL sorry for inconvenience. I have clarified my question.

Comment: @ashutosh in that case, my answer still convenience

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL are you still having some confusion?

Comment: No, you can check error existance as same as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can first do all database query and fill data to variable parexample $out, if you spot some error you can show this info to user. If everything pass without errors then you can do header function and output contents to user with echo $out.

Comment: If you have to set header at beginning of file only thing you can do is write error message to (par example) $_SESSION and redirect to another page where you will display error. But in this case downloader file will be incomplete.

Comment: How to redirect to a new page while download is in progress? Also that file will be of no use so how to cancel that download?

Comment: You right :( can't modify header after output start. I have no other idea:(

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry  = "SELECT * FROM `user_details` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($qry)) {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_object();
        $userName = $row->user_name;
        echo 'Username:' . $userName . "\n";    
    }
}
```